# authenticate_with_http_token method not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making an api with ruby on rails, and I am trying to use token based authentication. Everything works just fine, but Rails is saying that the method `authenticate_with_http_token` is undefined.

This is the error it is giving:

```
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"#\u003cNoMethodError: undefined method `authenticate_with_http_token' for #\u003cUsersController:0x007fa8ac16dee0\u003e\u003e","traces":{"Application Trace":[{"id":0,"trace":"app/controllers/users_controller.rb:59:in `authenticate_token'"},{"id":1,"trace":"app/controllers/users_controller.rb:55:in `authenticate'"}],"Framework Trace":[{"id":2,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.0.beta3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'"}
```

This is the code for my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  def index
    @users = User.all

    render json: @users
  end

  # GET /users/1
  def show
    render json: @user
  end

  # POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      render json: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :school_id, :auth_token, :password_digest)
    end

    def authenticate
      authenticate_token || render_unauthorized
    end

    def authenticate_token
      authenticate_with_http_token { |token, options|     User.find_by(auth_token: token) }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to include that in your ApplicationController or UsersController

```
include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to [use the new Rails 5 API-only?](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html)

If so you probably inherited your `ApplicationController` from

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::API`

instead of

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base`

Please take note that ActionController::API is a downsized version of ActionController which does not include [ALL](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#choosing-controller-modules) modules. One of the [ones left out](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#adding-other-modules) is actually `ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token`.

Including it in your ApplicationController (or a specialized controller if you just need it in one place) should fix it:

`include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic`